# Configure multiple strap pins with one circuit

Tags: bootstrap

I have a PHY that I need to configure in two ways, typically 'strap' resistors are used. In the application I have I don't have a processor on the board and I need to be able to set these straps in multiple configurations (at least two). Is there a good way to do set boot/strap digital lines in multiple configurations without using several fets, an FPGA/PLC or microprocessor?

Comment: No love for DIP switches?

Comment: I could do that... I was thinking more of an IC solution. But I left it open so a dip would probably work. I'd like to plug the unit into a pogo board and have it automatically set the phy to a different configuration so I can do a loopback test and test the PHY in a production environment.

Comment: Please include all the information needed (like that you'd want to be able to set the configuration on a pogo fixture) to answer the question into the question post.

Comment: Can you send enough current through your pogos to blow a fuse?

Comment: A few amps... in theory  thats a creative option...

Answer (score 2):

1. I remember the time when x86 processors could be overclocked with lead pencil markings; maybe that's a cheap option? 
    [image: Drawing with lead pencil on die carrier]
2. As The Photon [said](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/676800/configure-multiple-strap-pins-with-one-circuit#comment1802213_676800), DIP switches are the oldskool way of doing this
   [image: SMT DIP Switch, 4 Pos]
3. Of course, the good ole ugly "motherboard jumper" method of having a 2×N 2.54mm pitch pin header with a jumper cap for each resistor choice works as well. Make it a 3×1 array, and you can even pick one of two sides
   [image: Pin Header, SMT, 2×1]
4. If there's limited space, but complex configurations that are hard to achieve using DIP switches, pin headers etc: Mezzanine connector on motherboard, custom "Resistor daughterboad" (either different models which very clearly state on the silkscreen what they are, or a single model with variable resistor equipment, which can be easily labeled, or is designed in a way that makes the configuration quick to grasp.)
   [image: Mezzanine connector (f), 30pos]